# Upside down triangle using one for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to print an upside down right-angled triangle using one for-loop, without the **"\n"** in Javascript.
This is my code:

```js
function triangle(num) {
  triangleStr = "";
  for (let i = num; i > 0; i--) 
  {
    triangleStr += "#";
    console.log(triangleStr);
  }
}
triangle(5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, Just get rid of `triangleStr` and replace it inside `for-loop` with method `repeat`.

```js
function triangle(num) {
  for (let i = num; i > 0; i--) 
  {
    console.log("#".repeat(i));
  }
}
triangle(5);
```

***Result***

```
#####
####
###
##
#
```

Answer (score 3):

**1)** You can create a upside down right angled triangle as:

```
triangleStr = Array(i).fill("#").join("");
```

```js
function triangle(num) {
  triangleStr = "";
  for (let i = num; i > 0; i--) {
    triangleStr = Array(i).fill("#").join("");
    console.log(triangleStr);
  }
}
triangle(5);
```

**2)** You can also achieve the result using recursion as:

```js
function triangle(num) {
  if (num === 0) return;
  console.log(Array(num).fill("#").join(""));
  triangle(num - 1);
}
triangle(5);
```

**3)** Just using recursion

```js
function triangle(start, end) {
  if (start > end) return;
  triangle(start + 1, end);
  console.log(Array(start).fill("#").join(""));
}
triangle(1, 5);
```

---

**Edited:** Thanks to [`TAHERElMehdi`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14529779/taher-el-mehdi) who suggested this solution using `repeat` as:

You can replace all the above

```
Array(i).fill("#").join("");
```

with

```
"#".repeat(i)
```

Comment: Good approaches using both simples for-loop or recursion just a Note if you got the advantage of pre-built `repeat` method it would be more readable than creating an array then fill it and join it!

Comment: @TAHERElMehdi Indeed using `repeat` is a clean solution. Thanks, I'm not aware of `repeat`

Comment: Thank you too, I learned a lot of tricks and tips related to JS with you!

Comment: Thank you so much! `repeat` is a cleaner solution.